# How to permanently and continually monitor a socket using php and Linux

Tags: php, linux, sockets

I have a script that I can run successfully from the Linux command line.

This script runs in an infinite loop that opens and monitors a socket.

I have tried starting this script using a crop job, but then it stops after a few minutes.

I have also tried adding:

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

to the top of the code.

Essentially, I need this script to *always* be 'listening'.

Comment: It's not what you are looking for but why don't you set your cron to run every 5 or 10 seconds ? Do you really need to listen live ?

Comment: Thanks Serhat, but I'm listening for TCP connections from tracking devices and don't know when they will be trying to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't well suited for long-running jobs, but the connection can also change its status without your control.

You have to be able to handle such changes - for example, recognising when a network connection has been dropped, and then re-open it.

Comment: Thanks Alister, I'm listening for TCP communications and need to manipulate the data received in PHP (although this can happen post receive). What would you suggest as a better alternative to PHP?